# What topology do we give the set of polynomial functions

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, infinite-product

> Let $X$ be a topology space. $\mathbb C[t]$ be the set of polynomial functions. Define the map 
>   $$a: X \rightarrow \mathbb C[t], \quad  x \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x) t^i $$ 
>   where $a_i:X \rightarrow \mathbb C$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$ are maps.  :

**What topology do we give $\Bbb C[t]$ so that the following holds?**

> $a$ is continuous if and only if each $a_i$ is continuous.

EDIT: After thinking the comment for some time... I believe this is the topology. We identify $\Bbb C[t]$ as $\Bbb C^{\Bbb N}$. Hence. $a:X \rightarrow \Bbb C[t]$ is continuous iff each $a_i$ is continuous. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: When you say product topology, you view $\Bbb C[t]$ as $\Bbb C^n$ (though $n$ depends on $a$). Then the claim is the *definition* of product topology via universal property.

Comment: Actually @HagenvonEitzen, what exactly is this topology? I noticed my topology is not right, because the domain is required to be $\mathbb C$ which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: How do $a_i$'s relate to $a$??

Comment: $a_i$s are the components of $a$.

Comment: The set of polynomials corresponds to the set $c_{00}$ of all points in $\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}$ with only finitely many non-zero coordinates. Assuming you want the equivalence to hold for all $X$ and all $a$ you need the weakest topology that induces the product topology on each subproduct $\{x\in\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{N}: i >n \Rightarrow x_i=0\}$.